# MC/armored cable vs just NM

Tags: wiring

When is it necessary/mandated to use MC (metal clad) or armored cable vs just NM AKA "Romex"?

Comment: I'm not sure if MC is ever explicitly specified.  The requirements in the NEC says something like wiring "has to be protected from damage".  So NM is only one way of meeting this requirement.  I know, this is kind of wishy-washy, which is why I didn't make it an answer.

Comment: Think certain devices/appliances(furnace) require the use, but this from only what I see in my home.  NM needs to be protected below 8ft if in the open, but do not know if MC/armored cable meets protection level.

Comment: Oops - On my first comment, NM should have been MC!

Comment: This is a rather vague question essentially asking for a code digest. If you suspect that you need it somewhere, ask about that instead.

Comment: why is this closed? it is a "rule of thumb" question

Answer (score 6):

Typically in any multi-family residential use, (commercial, multiple-dwelling unit, etc.) or (non-mandated) if you are residential but don't enjoy mouse-chewed wiring.

Can also depend on locale (Chicago, NYC, etc.) as places where residential wiring is held to higher standards based on fire history so NM isn't welcome anywhere.

Code will **not** typically mandate the particular method/cable type, but will require use of conduit or suitable cable types.

Answer (score 4):

We can't possibly name all such requirements.  But I can think of a few.

- Industrial, commercial, high-density residential and other places metal conduit is normally required, but they need a flexible connection or wire whip (e.g. down to light troffers)
- Certain cities that don't accept Romex, e.g. Chicagoland
- Anyone who wants to fit an AFCI at the first receptacle instead of the breaker, per NEC 210.12(A)
- When someone sets a high standard of work

"physical protection from damage" is not on that list because MC doesn't provide that.  Neither does schedule 40 PVC, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Without providing a location and planned use scenario, the correct answer is to contact your local authority and find out what your specific requirements will be.  There are too many locally-mandated modifications separate from general code requirements to make any sort of blanket statement on what's allowed and what's not.